# How to make a line plot with several lines in R

Tags: r

I´m rather new to R, but I need to make a graph with several dotted lines, I´ve tried a couple of things, but nothing has worked so far.

My looks like this;

Distance´´´´Area´´´´Volume.all´´´´´´Volume.colonised
0-9 m´´´´´´´´´´´´1´´´´   ´´´´´´7804.199           ´´´´´´´´250.05
10-19 m ´´´´´´   1´´´´ ´´  1320.086 ´´´´´´        429.9361
20-29 m ´´´´´´   1    ´´´´´´´´2342.75´´´´´´´´´´´´            0

and so on...

I want to make a graph with the distance classes on the x-axes, and a dotted line each for;
Volume colonised from area 1
Volume all from area 1
Volume colonised from area 2
Volume all from area 2

Very grateful for help!

Comment: please post your sample data using `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

You should bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer`
then `ggplot` with `group=names, color = names`

```
library(tidyverse)
# dataframe
df <- tribble(
~Distance, ~Area, ~Volume.all, ~Volume.colonised,
"0-9 m", 1, 7804.199, 250.05,
"10-19 m", 1, 1320.086, 429.9361,
"20-29 m", 1, 2342.75, 0)

# long format
df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("Volume"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  )

# plot
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Distance, y=values, group=names, color = names)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]